# Remote Development & Building & JUnit with Eclipse (JAVA)

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, remote-debugging

First I would like to describe the configuration I am want to achieve.

1) Remote Windows machine - All required software(prerequisites for my project) is installed, DB configured, etc.
2) Local machines of the developers with Eclipse.

Previously they used RDP connection to the windows machine, to develop, but I am not satisfied with the speed and different lags which happen when the UI goes over network.

I want to set up this:

1)Eclipse is connected to the remote windows machine √ - works now, I am able to see file system.

2)Remote code base is added to the workspace on local machine, buildpath of the project is fullfilled with required libraries(which are also located on the remote filesystem)

3)All the regular tools are working, such as eclemma, it is possible to execute JUnit, etc.

I am having several ideas on the top of my head, such as rsync, using subversion, etc, but all of them, require setting up all the prerequisites on the local machines.. I would like to have all the listed stuff to be done remotely.

Currently I have eclipse able to connect to the remote windows machine, but I only can access and edit files, execute shell commands, and see file stucture, this is more like an advanced remote text editor - I would like to be able more features of eclipse and 3rd party plugins..

Are there any existing solutions for that?

---

Not having resources is not a bad idea, but, since the development process involves changing sources, to compile those on the remote machine will require to sync them somehow.

Here is the breakdown of tasks per location: RemoteMachine - compiling, execution of JUnit(results should be displayed in Eclipse in a regular JUnit tab).

Local Machine - Eclipse running, coding, sources should be in sync with remote machine, and in the shell windows of RSE I will be able to execute a complete build process(in our project it is different from Eclipse's source compilation)

Main idea is to replace a process where developers work on RDP machines, and to switch to using eclipse locally, without a need to setup all the prerequisite software on local machine.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen _where_?  Also not having resources on a local file system with Eclipse is a very bad idea?

Comment: Replied above, since my comment was too long :)

Comment: Considered having a CI-server watch and build your source repository?

Comment: `I am having several ideas on the top of my head, such as rsync, using subversion, etc, but all of them, require setting up all the prerequisites on the local machines`

I agree with @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. I think you should introduce a source control management (like subversion), a CI-server (like Jenkins) and probably a build tool (like Maven). If you provide a pre-configured Eclipse, everything should work out of the box without having every developer spending a day setting up the environment.

Comment: Thanks, now I am thinking about CI. Yes we have a continious integration server with Jenkins, but since there are many different branches where every developer is working on his own feature, I need a way to execute parametrized Jenkins jobs, specifying the SVN branch they are working on. Is there a way to do that? I checked several plugins and all of them allow just to start a job.